# How to make sure that if a file exists, it starts a Process.Start?

Tags: c#

I'm currently creating a custom launcher for a FiveM server. I want to run `Process.Start` if FiveM folder exists in `\AppData\Local`.

- *Edit*

I would like to do that if the folder exists so if fivem is installed, it starts the software, otherwise it opens an error message

Here's my code:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData");

    if (!Directory.Exists("//FiveM")) 
    {
        Process.Start("fivem://connect/144.217.11.186:30120");
        MessageBox.Show("Veuillez patienter quelques secondes");
    }
    else
    {
        Hide();
        error error = new error();
        error.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the full path and file name of the file you are checking for. Also GetEnvironmentVariable gets you a value, you aren't using it.

Comment: Also, better to use: `string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData))`.

Comment: Are you expecting `FiveM` to be a _file_ or a _folder_?

Comment: So, what's your _question_? What does the code you posted do? How is that different from what you wanted it to do?

Comment: You said _if the "FiveM" file exists then it's a Process.Start_, but the code logic is _if the "FiveM" file __doesn't__ exist then it's a Process.Start_

Comment: @shingo I would like to do that if the folder exists so if fivem is installed, it starts the software, otherwise it opens an error message

Comment: `!File.Exists("//FiveM"))` What does ! do?

Comment: I don't know, I tried to group tutorials together because I couldn't find any that explained to me how

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_logical_operators.htm Read that, understand what `!` does and then read the below answer.

Comment: @mjwills Ok, i've deleted the '!' but now it's just starting the error even if the FiveM folder exist

Comment: @IanMercer So i've tried your method but i don't know how to make that if the FiveM folder exist, then run my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the special folder, add your path to it (using [methods on System.IO.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8), not by concatenating strings), then check if that directory exists:

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData));
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "fivem");
if (Directory.Exists(path)) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it's working! It took me 13 hours to figure it out, but you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Use `Directory.Exists` to check if a folder exists.

Comment: Okay, thanks but i can't reach the FiveM folder because it's in the appdata/local folder, how could i make it work?